# Problem with gnuplot in the construction of the histogram

Tags: label, gnuplot, histogram

everybody:

I'm having problems when it comes to representing the data in the form of a histogram.
I do not know very well how to clearly express what I intend, but my idea is:

- 3 groups of columns (carbides, borides and nitrides)
- in each group of columns, 4 columns (hafnium, zirconium, titanium and 
    tantalum) each with a grid type.

So far, I have done what appears below, but it does not allow me to continue

My current code is:

```
reset
fontSpec(s) = sprintf("Times-Roman, %d", s)
set term post eps enhanced fontSpec(16)
set output 'TVsG.eps'

set grid
set auto y
set auto x

ticsFont=fontSpec(16)
set xtics font ticsFont
set ytics font ticsFont

set ylabel "Temperature" font fontSpec(25) offset char -1,0
set xlabel "Group" font fontSpec(25) offset 0,char -1

set style fill pattern border -1
set style data histograms
set boxwidth 1.0
set style histogram clustered gap 1

keyFont=fontSpec(18)
set key spacing 2 font keyFont
set key at graph 0.25, 0.9

fn(v) = sprintf("%.1f", v)

plot \
    for [COL=2:4] 'data.txt' using COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader fs 
pattern 2, \
    'data.txt' u ($0-1-1./6):2:(fn($2)) w labels font fontSpec(14) offset 
 char 0,0.5 t '' , \
     'data.txt' u ($0-1-1./6):2:(fn($3)) w labels font fontSpec(14) offset 
 char 0,0.5 t '' , \
    'data.txt' u ($0-1+1./6):3:(fn($4)) w labels font fontSpec(14) offset 
char 0,0.5 t ''
```

and my data file

```
Material    Hafnium Zirconium   Titanium    Tantalum
Carbide 3958    3400    3100    3768  
Boride  3380    3245    3225    3040        
Nitride 3385    2950    2950    2700
```

The main problem I have now is the following error:

```
gnuplot> load 'gnuplot2.txt'
         "gnuplot2.txt" line 34: warning: Cannot find or open file "data"
         "gnuplot2.txt" line 34: warning: Cannot find or open file "data"
         "gnuplot2.txt" line 34: warning: Cannot find or open file "data"
         "gnuplot2.txt" line 34: warning: Cannot find or open file "data"
         "gnuplot2.txt" line 34: warning: Cannot find or open file "data"
         "gnuplot2.txt" line 34: warning: Cannot find or open file "data"
         "gnuplot2.txt" line 34: No data in plot
```

Now I'm at a point, I do not know how to continue

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot does not find the data file. I see two possible reasons:

1. The name of the datafile is wrong

The script has something like `plot "data.txt"`, the error message mentions a file `"data"`, note the missing `.txt`. => Check your script and the actual file name, it might be a simple typo or a missing file extension.

2. The data file is not in the directory where it is expected.

Add the command `pwd` (print working directory) as the first command in your script. It will print the directory where it expects the data file. If it is not the correct directory, you can:

- move or copy your data file to this directory
- use the `cd` command to change to correct directory
- start gnuplot from the correct directory
- use the `plot` command with the file name including path information

You use the `load` command and gnuplot seems to find the script. So I think most probably the data file should be in the same directory as the script `gnuplot2.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

[So far, this is the image that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJuGj.png)

Indeed, the problem was when selecting the directory in which the data was.

The problem now is that I do not know how I can change the format to give it a different color. Besides, I want to add the compound label on top of each column.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the answer did help, then consider accepting it. If there is another question, then please ask another question. Please don't hide your question in an answer.